# Different datetypes in ieee citation

Tags: ieee-style

I am using:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
```

and I get an output like this:

```
moodle. “moodle/moodle: Moodle - the world’s open source learning platform”. GitHub, Ed. (2022), [Online]. Available: https://github.com/moodle/moodle (visited on 02/09/2022).
```

But if I google for how to cite websites in ieee I found something like this (from https://citationsy.com/styles/ieee-with-url):

```
[1]M. Tran, “Barack Obama To Be America’s First Black President”, 05-Nov.-2008. [Online]. Available: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2008/nov/05/uselections20083. [Accessed: 28-Feb.-2022]
```

So why are the dates completely different? I thought ieee is always ieee or are there many types? And if yes, what is the right one? My Prof. does not care which one I use but it should be "consistent". So what would you suggest and how could I change the dates in general?

Maybe it is helpful if I add the related bib-entry:

```
@online{moodle.2022,
 author = {moodle},
 editor = {GitHub},
 year = {2022},
 title = {{moodle/moodle: Moodle - the world's open source learning platform}},
 url = {https://github.com/moodle/moodle},
 urldate = {2022-02-09},
 abstract = {Moodle - the world's open source learning platform - moodle/moodle: Moodle - the world's open source learning platform}
}
```

Comment: If you want to use the `.cls` provided by https://citationstyles.org you should try: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citation-style-language instead of biblatex

Comment: @DG' thanks, but why is it in general different? I mean, my setting seems to be the default setting, and it's different to most ieee examples I found. I am wondering why this is the case.

Comment: The reference section in https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Editorial-Style-Manual.pdf is rather *compact*, so there is some room for different interpretations.